# How I can run single Jenkins job by previously defined rules

Tags: jenkins

I'd like to get a hint how (which plugin) it is possible run SINGLE Jenkins job by the user chosen way. User MUST be able to choose the job he/she wants to run and choose the rule of execution:

E.g:

1. Create only jar files;
2. Create jars and send them over ssh
3. Create jars, generate documentation, etc...

I've found out a few plugins (Artifactory, Release plugin) but seems they don't support such logic.

I know that such thing can be implemented by creating several jobs, but this would require additional disk space.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve my issue, I've decided to create a few Jenkins jobs with the same custom workspace. So that, when a IT engineer runs any of these "connected" (which have the same workspace) jobs the workspace is updated (have a look at the CVS rules for your job) and that's why we avoid wasting of space.

Additionally, its (job) behaviour can be configured easily => the sets of rules (shell scripts, gradle, batch etc) and their sequence in order to achieve the desired result.

The last advantage, but not the least one, is that the security (access control) is still very easy to configure.

I think, that is the correct way.

Comment: Just be aware that with your solution only one of those jobs should run at any given time, otherwise the workspace is changed by multiple jobs at the same time. There is a plugin for exclusive access that might help enforce this.

Comment: @Petrik you are quite right. By the way there are a few plugins can help: _Build Blocker Plugin_ and more powerful  _Throttle Concurrent Builds Plugin_